# Can we change the view of a Sharepoint list to calendar view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list

I have created a SharePoint list that I am using in my Microsoft flow for leave approval system.
The list looks great with all the requests being tracked there.
However, would it be possible to change the view of this list to a calendar view, i.e. same list but in a calendar?

I do have some calculated columns, so not sure how that would work in a calendar. But if somehow I can incorporate my list into a calendar, that would be great to have a calendar view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a calendar view, you will need to have two date fields in your list to set for **Time Interval** in view settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to List Settings.
2. Scroll down to **Views** section.
3. Click on **Create view**.
4. Select **Calendar View** option.
5. Give View name, set leave start date in **Begin** and end date in **End** for **Time Interval** dropdowns.
6. Select appropriate columns for **Calendar Columns** section.
7. Click **OK**.

Comment: Thank you :-) This worked as I had expected.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3: Calendar View on any list or library for your reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/

Comment: Thanks Lisa, this article is for sure going to help me in my projects :-)